# How to select all lines below a current line in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

Is there a way to select all lines below a current selected line in PyCharm (similarly to how in Mac you can use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>down</kbd> to select the lines)?
The <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>right</kbd> / <kbd>left</kbd> work just fine, but the "up" and "down" don't work.

I'm using a Mac.

Comment: This question is off-topic and not suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Okay... I'm using Pycharm to code so I don't quite understand. But, how do I close it?

Comment: This post is "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) cc @Tyler2P

Comment: @Penguin Posts get closed by other users than the author.

Comment: @Scratte thanks! So if I understand your first comment, this post is okay and shouldn't be closed?

Comment: @Penguin Voting to close is not clear cut on Stack Overflow. I think it's fine as per my understanding of the help page. Others may not agree. It will help you a lot if you read the pages in help center, if you wish to continue asking Questions, so you have a better understanding of what is expected of Questions.

Comment: @Scratte will do from now on :) Thanks for the guidance

Comment: Note: On windows it's generally ctrl + shift + end.

Comment: My bad! Should have mentioned that I'm using a Mac. Just updated my question

Comment: If "cmd + shift + right / left" does nothing, you could map them, no? [PyCharm keyboard shortcuts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/mastering-keyboard-shortcuts.html#choose-keymap) has a link to how to [Configuring keyboard shortcuts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html). but according to [Key combination cheat sheet](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/pycharm/docs/PyCharm_ReferenceCard_mac.pdf) "cmd + shift + right / left" moves the current line up and down.

Comment: Adding to the list here [Where to ask a question about an IDE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20251/where-to-ask-a-question-about-an-ide/) and [Where is the line between programming-specific tools and programming?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119250/where-is-the-line-between-programming-specific-tools-and-programming) which, in my opinion, both says that this type of Question is OK for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Scratte thanks for the help! Not sure why the question is closed since I believe you're right. I managed to solve this using [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000022679-Keyboard-Shortcut-Select-text-to-the-beginning-end-of-document). The keyboard shortcut name is called "Move Caret to Text End/Start with Selection"

Comment: You're welcome :) I don't expect this will be reopened :( Fn-Cmd-Shift-[Right Arrow]/[left Arrow] it is then. 4 keys at the same time! Not sure I understand why it's not Up/Down Arrow though.

Comment: @Scratte yea I'm not sure either. What I did was changing the keyboard shortcut name "Move Caret to Text End" to Cmd-Shift-Down. So only 3 keys (and much more intuitive)

Answer (score 2):

Hit `End` to go the end of the current line and then `Ctrl + shift + end` will select all lines below your cursor.

That's the key binding for this functionality:
[image]

You can find it in `Settings -> Keymap -> Editor actions`.

Comment: What is the logic for overriding the default system shortcut that presumably most users already have learned as muscle memory? I find this incredibly unintuitive and frustrating

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of... On windows, `ctrl + shift + pg up / pg dn` might help